# Flag review offering only 'Other (needs ♦ moderator attention)' as a choice

Tags: bug

Why does the Review section of the main site prompt me to review flags on the post show below but only offers me the **Other (needs ♦ moderator attention)** choice?

This is the first time I see something like this; it looks like a bug to me.

[image]

Comment: other features of the review option seem a little flaky this morning -- the red buttons offering "no action needed" or "skip" are "live", but the "i'm done" button is grayed out, and the "improve" isn't there at all.  maybe the site is undergoing maintenance, but it would be nice (if that's true) for that to be announced somewhere, perhaps in an attention-getting box above the "community bulletin" box.

Comment: This is because the actual post you are/were reviewing was deleted. The other options usually presented (it is spam; it is offensive, abusive, or hate speech; it is not an answer; it has invalid flags) make little sense here. Only moderator attention does. The stranger question is why you are having the review posts that are/have been deleted. It may be a timing issue where the post was deleted while you were in the review queue (but the time stamps don't corroborate that...).